# Rendering a part of a SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have a *SDL_rect* named `mapRect` containing my map consisting of tiles, and some of that tiles have textures loader. This rectangle is much times higher and wider than my window size.
Am I able to render just a part of it? Or shall I do it other way, for instance somehow cast this *SDL_Rect* into *SDL_texture* and then render it using `SDL_RenderCopyEx()` function (like it was done in the [Lazy Foo's SDL scrolling tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/30_scrolling/index.php))?

PS. I also found [`SDL_RenderDrawRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect) function, but I'm not pretty sure how it exacly works. Can I use it to solve my problem?

Comment: Taking the purpose of *rendering part of a rect* to be *spend time/power economically*: what is the purpose of rendering it in the first place?

Comment: I like it when hyperlinks are given captions helping to decide following or ignoring them, like [`SDL_RenderDrawRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect).

Comment: I thought it will be the best way to solve the level scrolling problem. I also thought about rendering only the visible part of the map, and this approach seems optimistic, however I will have to deal with the generation of parts of margin tiles near the window border

Comment: PS. I fixed the link, thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly mapRect has some texture to it and you are using mapRect as a srcRect. In that case you have to use a different srcRect in SDL_RenderCopy() which has .W == screenwidth and .H == screenheight and .X & .Y as the top left corner of the part you want to render

Comment: (As an aside: `"preformatted" decoration` of snippets uses just single `\`` "backtick".)

Comment: An SDL_rect is just the coordinates of a rectangle. It doesn't have any textures. It doesn't have any map. It doesn't have any tiles.